# UIControl from xib crashes on ios 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uicontrol, nscoder

I create a custom UIControl ( MyControl ) in storyboard. on ios 8 and ios 9 everything is fine and there are no crashes in my app. But  on ios 7 and, as example, iphone 4, the app crashes when trying to load the view controller which contains this control. The debugger is highlighting this line:

> typeof(self) loadedView = self.viewFromNib;

MyControl.h:

```
@interface MyControl : ControlFromXib
```

ControlFromXib.h:

```
@interface ControlFromXib : UIControl

- (void)commonInit;
@end
```

ControlFromXib.m:

```
- (instancetype)viewFromNib
{
    typeof(self) view = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:self.nibName owner:nil options:nil].firstObject;
    return view;
}

- (NSString *)nibName
{
    return NSStringFromClass([self class]);
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self = self.viewFromNib;
        [self commonInit];
        self.frame = frame;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)awakeAfterUsingCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self.subviews.count == 0) {
        typeof(self) loadedView = self.viewFromNib;

        loadedView.frame = self.frame;
        loadedView.autoresizingMask = self.autoresizingMask;
        loadedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints;

        for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.constraints) {
            id firstItem = constraint.firstItem;
            if (firstItem == self) {
                firstItem = loadedView;
            }
            id secondItem = constraint.secondItem;
            if (secondItem == self) {
                secondItem = loadedView;
            }
            [loadedView addConstraint:
                    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:firstItem
                                                 attribute:constraint.firstAttribute
                                                 relatedBy:constraint.relation
                                                    toItem:secondItem
                                                 attribute:constraint.secondAttribute
                                                multiplier:constraint.multiplier
                                                  constant:constraint.constant]];
        }

        self = loadedView;
    }

    [self commonInit];

    return self;
}

- (void)commonInit
{

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the constraint attributes and compare to the list [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSLayoutAttribute). The following attributes were added in iOS 8, and will crash on iOS 7 (and earlier) if referenced in a xib or in code.

- NSLayoutAttributeLastBaseline
- NSLayoutAttributeFirstBaseline
- NSLayoutAttributeLeftMargin
- NSLayoutAttributeRightMargin
- NSLayoutAttributeTopMargin
- NSLayoutAttributeBottomMargin
- NSLayoutAttributeLeadingMargin
- NSLayoutAttributeTrailingMargin
- NSLayoutAttributeCenterXWithinMargins
- NSLayoutAttributeCenterYWithinMargins